# Define range with last row & Intersect activecell and range

Tags: excel, vba, intersect

I'm new to VBA and am currently trying to define a range within a datasheet from column h11 to last data row in column h in order to run a macro, if the activecell is within that range.

VB tells me "Object Variable or With block variable not set" when defining rng1 (and probably rng2 as well).

I would like feedback on 2 things:
What do I do to fix this error?
How do I proceed with the intersect function, when I fix the first error?

I would really appreciate all help. I've been at it for a quite a while now and seems to be stuck.
I've tried `rng1 = range(range("H11") ,range("H" & Lastrow))`.
Please let me know if there is something I can do to learn faster or better - youtube videos or similar is very much appreciated.

````
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

rng1 = Range("H11:H" & lastrow)
rng2 = Range("I11:I" & lastrow)

'Sort on Product
    If Intersect(activecell, rng1) = True Then```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines should be:

```
set rng1 = Range("H11:H" & lastrow)
set rng2 = Range("I11:I" & lastrow)
```

With that, the intersect function should be:

```
if not Intersect(activecell, rng1) is nothing then
```

Comment: Thanks! Why should it be set? I read that `Set rng1 =` should be the same as `rng =`. If I want the rest of the code to run if the activecell is actually intersecting, what should it then be? The opposite of nothing?

Comment: When working with objects in VBA you have to use the "Set" keyword in order to assign them. As for the other question, the opposite of nothing is defined by the "Not" keywork before Intersect. Please remember to mark the answer with the green tick in order to help other find it.